# Varying the size of an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have written a program which generates a random array and sorts it by using both the insertion and quicksort algorithms. The program also measures the runtime of each function. The size of the array is defined in the preamble as a parameterised macro `L`. My question is:

> How can I test both sorting algorithms with arrays of various sizes in a single execution?

I want my program to sort arrays of size `L=10, 100, 1000, 5000` and `10000` in one execution. My program code is detailed below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//Random Array Length
#define MAX 100
#define L 10

void naive_sort(int[]);
void smarter_sort(int[],int,int);
void swap(int[],int,int);
int choose_piv(int[],int,int);

int main(){
    int i, a[L], b[L];
    clock_t tic, toc;

    //Generate an array of random numbers
    for(i=0; i<L; i++)
        a[i]= rand() % (MAX+1);

    //Define b identical to a for fair comparison
    for(i=0; i<L; i++)
        b[i]=a[i];

    //Unsorted Array
    printf("\nUnsorted array:   ");
    for(i=0; i<L; i++)
            printf("%d    ", a[i]);

    //Insertion Sort (1e)
    tic = clock();
    naive_sort(a);
    printf("\nInsertion Sort:   ");
            for(i=0; i<L; i++)
                printf("%d    ", a[i]);
    toc = clock();
    printf("  (Runtime: %f seconds)\n", (double)(toc-tic)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    //Quicksort (1f)
    tic = clock();
    smarter_sort(b,0,L-1);
    printf("Quicksort:        ");
            for(i=0; i<L; i++)
                printf("%d    ", b[i]);
    toc = clock();
   printf("  (Runtime: %f seconds)\n", (double)(toc-tic)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

   return 0;
}

void naive_sort(int a[]){
    int i, j, t;
    for(i=1; i < L; i++){
        t=a[i];
        j=i-1;
        while((t < a[j]) && (j >= 0)){
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1]=t;
    }
}

void smarter_sort(int a[], int l, int r){
    if(r > l){
        int piv = choose_piv(a, l, r);
        smarter_sort(a, l, piv-1);
        smarter_sort(a, piv+1, r);
    }
}

void swap(int a[], int i, int j){
    int t=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=t;
}

int choose_piv(int a[], int l, int r){
    int pL = l, pR = r;
    int piv = l;
    while (pL < pR){
        while(a[pL] < a[piv])
            pL++;
        while(a[pR] > a[piv])
            pR--;
        if(pL < pR)
            swap(a, pL, pR);
    }
    swap(a, piv, pR);
    return pR;
}
```

I would appreciate any feedback.

---

**EDIT:** I modified the code as suggested, and it worked for the small values. But for the quicksort case `L=100` and beyond it, I don't get any output:

[image]

and as you can see, the few outputs I get are zero. What's wrong with the code?

```c
/*
 * Task 1, question h
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//Random Array Length
#define MAX 100

void perf_routine(int);
void naive_sort(int[],int);
void smarter_sort(int[],int,int);
void swap(int[],int,int);
int choose_piv(int[],int,int);

int main(){
    perf_routine(10);
    perf_routine(100);
    perf_routine(1000);
    perf_routine(5000);
    perf_routine(10000);
   return 0;
}

void perf_routine(int L){
    int i, a[L], b[L];
        clock_t tic, toc;

        printf("Arrays of Length %d:\n", L);

        //Generate an array of random numbers
        for(i=0; i<L; i++)
            a[i]= rand() % (MAX+1);

        //Define b identical to a for fair comparison
        for(i=0; i<L; i++)
            b[i]=a[i];

        //Insertion Sort (1e)
        tic = clock();
        naive_sort(a, L);
        toc = clock();
        printf("Insertion Sort Runtime: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc-tic)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        //Quicksort (1f)
        tic = clock();
        smarter_sort(b,0,L-1);
        toc = clock();
       printf("Quicksort Runtime: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc-tic)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

void naive_sort(int a[], int L){
    int i, j, t;
    for(i=1; i < L; i++){
        t=a[i];
        j=i-1;
        while((t < a[j]) && (j >= 0)){
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1]=t;
    }
}

void smarter_sort(int a[], int l, int r){
    if(r > l){
        int piv = choose_piv(a, l, r);
        smarter_sort(a, l, piv-1);
        smarter_sort(a, piv+1, r);
    }
}

void swap(int a[], int i, int j){
    int t=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=t;
}

int choose_piv(int a[], int l, int r){
    int pL = l, pR = r;
    int piv = l;
    while (pL < pR){
        while(a[pL] < a[piv])
            pL++;
        while(a[pR] > a[piv])
            pR--;
        if(pL < pR)
            swap(a, pL, pR);
    }
    swap(a, piv, pR);
    return pR;
}
```

Comment: Make the array size an additional parameter to your functions instead of a global constant.

Comment: @MOehm I was thinking of doing something like that, but I wasn't sure how to go about it. Could you clarify?

Comment: Overall, you might want to look at the standard C `qsort` function prototype, for ideas how to write such function interfaces in generic ways.

Comment: in naive sort, invert the conditions of the while loop so it never tries to compute a[j] if j<0.

Comment: @Puck You mean just switch the order round?

Comment: if you put ((j >= 0) && (t < a[j])), with the operator &&, if the first condition is not true, it doesn't try the second, meaning no seg fault if j is out of bound of a.

Comment: @Puck I tried that but it still didn't go beyond 100 :(

Comment: Maybe edit the post so we can see the current state of the problem. Did you replaced the array with dynamic allocation (malloc)? (don't know if related to your problem, but it bother me to see that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When arrays are passed to functions, they are passed as (or "decay into") pointer to their first element. There is no way to know about the size of the array.

It is therefore very common to pass the actual length as additional parameter to the function. An example of your naive sort with three arrays of different size if below.

Of course, one must take care to keep the array and length in sync. Passing a length that is too big may result in undefined behaviour. For example, calling `fill(tiny, LARGE)` in the example below may result in disaster.

(Aside: An array may have a maximum length or capacity and an actual length. For example if you want to read up to ten numbers from a file, you must pass an array of length 10, but if there are only four numbers read, you are dealing with two additional parameters here: the possible array length, 10, and the actual length, 4. That's not the case here, though.)

Well, here goes. All three array functions have the same signature: They take an array and its length.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void sort(int a[], size_t len)
{
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        int t = a[i];

        j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && t < a[j]) {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }

        a[j + 1] = t;
    }
}

void fill(int a[], size_t len)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() / (1.0 + RAND_MAX) * 100;
    }
}

void print(int a[], size_t len)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i) printf(", ");
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }

    puts("");
}

#define TINY 3
#define MEDIUM 10
#define LARGE 15

int main(void)
{
    int tiny[TINY];
    int medium[MEDIUM];
    int large[LARGE];

    srand(time(NULL));

    fill(tiny, TINY);
    fill(medium, MEDIUM);
    fill(large, LARGE);

    print(tiny, TINY);
    print(medium, MEDIUM);
    print(large, LARGE);

    sort(tiny, TINY);
    sort(medium, MEDIUM);
    sort(large, LARGE);

    print(tiny, TINY);
    print(medium, MEDIUM);
    print(large, LARGE);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would, in each function gives the length of the array in parameters and make sure you don't try to reach element outside of array, for example swap would become:

```
int swap(int *a, int length, int i, int j)
{
    if(i>=length || j>=length)
        return -1;
    int t=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=t;
    return 0;
}
```

Also note the return -1 or 0 to indicates a failure. Apply that to the rest of the code and you'll have something that can be applied to any array.

Comment: But what about varying the random array being created in the main function?

Comment: No problem here, if you want to have the length in a variable, use malloc:
int len = 5678;
int * a = malloc(len*sizeof(int));
for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        a[i]= rand() % (MAX+1);

Don't forget to free, particularly if you put that in a loop to test several values!!

Comment: Would it be wrong if I put all the contents of the main function in another void function `perf(int L)` and instantiate it for different values of `L` in `main`? Why would I have to modify `swap`?

Comment: @LukeCollins: You can put the core code into a separate function, which you then call with a length parameter, `perf(L)`. But you'd still have to communicate the array length to all functions that you call, because `L` would be local to `perf`. That means that all array functions should have both array data and length as arguments. (The modification of `swap` is arguably not necessary. It just provides you with a possibility to enforce the array bounds. In your example, I'd leave `swap` as it is.)

Comment: Yeah, actually the smarter_sort already take care the length of the array in its argument. You would just have to add the length as a parameter of naive_sort to make it proper.
But there is still a reason to modify the other functions: to really make sure no segmentation fault will occur, even if you use these function in another context (for example the swap function can be useful for other things)

Comment: I've edited the post to show you guys what I've done, it's still not working  now. :(

Comment: Don't use array with variable length, instead use malloc-free at begin-end of perf_routine: int * a = malloc(L*sizeof(int); --> free(a);

Comment: @Puck Can you clarify a bit more on how to use `malloc`? I forgot how it works.