# Why can't my program work for large arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35175065/varying-the-size-of-an-array-in-c) question on the site earlier, whose solution I managed to get to (more or less). In a nutshell, I need to test the insertion and quicksort algorithms for arrays of various sizes, and see how their runtime varies with respect to array size.

The only issue is that my program seems to freeze when it tries to calculate the runtime of the quicksort algorithm for arrays with 100 elements and larger. I've tried debugging the code and I can't seem to understand why this is the case. When I run it, this is the output I get:

[image]

Why does it stop there? and why is the runtime zero? Can anyone help me with this? In my original question, some commenters suggested I use `malloc` but I'm not sure how to go about it.

My code is listed below, I'd appreciate any suggestions.

```c
/*
 * Task 1, question h
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//Random Array Length
#define MAX 1000

void perf_routine(int);
void naive_sort(int[],int);
void smarter_sort(int[],int,int);
void swap(int[],int,int);
int choose_piv(int[],int,int);

int main(){
    perf_routine(10);
    perf_routine(100);
    perf_routine(1000);
    perf_routine(5000);
    perf_routine(10000);
   return 0;
}

void perf_routine(int L){
    int i, a[L], b[L];
        clock_t tic, toc;

        printf("Arrays of Length %d:\n", L);

        //Generate an array of random numbers
        for(i=0; i<L; i++)
            a[i]= rand() % (MAX+1);

        //Define b identical to a for fair comparison
        for(i=0; i<L; i++)
            b[i]=a[i];

        //Insertion Sort (1e)
        tic = clock();
        naive_sort(a, L);
        toc = clock();
        printf("Insertion Sort Runtime: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc-tic)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        //Quicksort (1f)
        tic = clock();
        smarter_sort(b,0,L-1);
        toc = clock();
       printf("Quicksort Runtime: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc-tic)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

void naive_sort(int a[], int L){
    int i, j, t;
    for(i=1; i < L; i++){
        t=a[i];
        j=i-1;
        while((j >= 0) && (t < a[j])){
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1]=t;
    }
}

void smarter_sort(int a[], int l, int r){
    if(r > l){
        int piv = choose_piv(a, l, r);
        smarter_sort(a, l, piv-1);
        smarter_sort(a, piv+1, r);
    }
}

void swap(int a[], int i, int j){
    int t=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=t;
}

int choose_piv(int a[], int l, int r){
    int pL = l, pR = r;
    int piv = l;
    while (pL < pR){
        while(a[pL] < a[piv])
            pL++;
        while(a[pR] > a[piv])
            pR--;
        if(pL < pR)
            swap(a, pL, pR);
    }
    swap(a, piv, pR);
    return pR;
}
```

Comment: Seems you forgot to increment `pL` and decrement `pR` after swapping. This may cause infinite loop.

Comment: Have you tried stepping your code through a debugger such as gdb?

Answer (score 1):

`choose_piv` can go into an infinite loop if there are duplicate values in the array.  If `a[pL]`, `a[pR]`, and `a[piv]` are the same, then the inner `while` loops both exit immediately, the `swap` has no effect (since both values are the same), and the outer `while` loop will loop forever.  Try it with a small array where all element are the same (e.g., all zero).

Comment: How can this be avoided?

Comment: You need to understand, and fix, the algorithm.  Obviously it's incorrect as implemented.  If you understand the intent, then you should be able to fix it.  Just think about what you expect it to do if two values are the same.  Then modify it to match your expectation.

Comment: I think that if I change the `>` signs to `>=` for the nested while conditions, the problem should be resolved. Is that correct?